# Android- Unfortunately App has stopped

Tags: android

I am developing a Launcher for android and while launching the app it gives me this error

My Code

MainActivity

```
package com.Aaps.androidlauncher;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    DrawerAdapter drawerAdapterObject;
    GridView drawerGrid;
    IntentFilter filter;
     class Pac
     {
        Drawable icon;
        String name;
        String label;
     }
     Pac[] pacs;
     PackageManager pm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pm = getPackageManager();
        set_pacs();
        drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        drawerAdapterObject = new DrawerAdapter(this,pacs);
        drawerGrid.setAdapter(drawerAdapterObject);
        drawerGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListener(this,pacs,pm));

        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED);
        filter.addDataScheme("package");
        registerReceiver(new PacReciever(),filter);

     }

public void set_pacs()
{
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> pacList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    pacs = new Pac[pacList.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < pacList.size();i++)
    {
        pacs[i] = new Pac();
        pacs[i].icon=pacList.get(i).loadIcon(pm);
        pacs[i].name = pacList.get(i).activityInfo.packageName;
        pacs[i].label = pacList.get(i).loadLabel(pm).toString();
    }
    new SortApps().exchange_sort(pacs);
    drawerAdapterObject = new DrawerAdapter(this,pacs);
    drawerGrid.setAdapter(drawerAdapterObject);
    drawerGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerClickListener(this,pacs,pm));
}

    public class PacReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            set_pacs();
        }

    }
}
```

The Main Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xm lns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Aaps.androidlauncher.MainActivity" >

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/Drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Grey_Transparent"
        android:columnWidth="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="30dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="30dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/handle" />

</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `@color/Grey_transparent` is from the xml i made which has this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    `enter code here`    <color name="Grey_Transparent">#80000000</color>
    </resources>
```

DrawerAdapter class

```
package com.Aaps.androidlauncher;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context mContext;
MainActivity.Pac[] pacsForAdapter;
public DrawerAdapter(Context c, MainActivity.Pac pacs[])
{
    mContext = c;
    pacsForAdapter = pacs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pacsForAdapter.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
}
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)               mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
        viewHolder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    viewHolder.text.setText(pacsForAdapter[pos].label);
    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(pacsForAdapter[pos].icon);
    return convertView;
}

}
```

the DrawerClickListener class

```
package com.Aaps.androidlauncher;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class DrawerClickListener implements OnItemClickListener{
Context mContext;
MainActivity.Pac[] pacsForAdapter;
PackageManager pmForListener;
public DrawerClickListener(Context c,MainActivity.Pac[] pacs , PackageManager pm)
{
    mContext = c;
    pacsForAdapter = pacs;
    pmForListener = pm;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
    Intent launchIntent = pmForListener.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pacsForAdapter[pos].name);
    mContext.startActivity(launchIntent);
}

}
```

Logcat

```
11-01 00:01:47.734: D/dalvikvm(1920): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 4% free 2817K/2920K, paused 21ms,     total 22ms
11-01 00:01:47.734: I/dalvikvm-heap(1920): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.409MB for 635808-byte allocation
11-01 00:01:47.794: D/dalvikvm(1920): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 3438K/3544K, paused 53ms, total 53ms
11-01 00:01:48.254: D/dalvikvm(1920): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 26K, 3% free 3892K/3992K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
11-01 00:01:48.334: D/AndroidRuntime(1920): Shutting down VM
11-01 00:01:48.334: W/dalvikvm(1920): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d0cb20)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920): Process: com.Aaps.androidlauncher, PID: 1920
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Aaps.androidlauncher/com.Aaps.androidlauncher.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at com.Aaps.androidlauncher.MainActivity.set_pacs(MainActivity.java:66)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at com.Aaps.androidlauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-01 00:01:48.344: E/AndroidRuntime(1920):     ... 11 more
```

And i am a noob so please help

and ask for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `drawerGrid` in `set_pacs();` before initialize,i.e. your `drawerGrid` caused `NullPointerException`,So change

```
 set_pacs();
 drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
```

to

```
  drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
  set_pacs();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `drawerGrid` is `null`

Change order of this lines

```
   set_pacs();
   drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
```

into

```
  drawerGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);     
  set_pacs();
```